Using DFT to Model Gamma-Point Phonons and Color Centers in Silicon Carbide
I'm an undergraduate student. In May, I was admitted to participate in an academic year-long internship with the Semiconductor Research Corporation.
Soon, I need to secure a semiconductor or technology research project guided by a professor at my university.
I essentially have professors that would sign off on a project of my choosing. I have some experience in the language C and Python, and have studied one graduate course in quantum chemistry.
Initially, one professor at my school sent me the attached papers about spin defects in silicon carbide, which is a material that has emerged as an exciting platform for quantum information science applications due to its unique crystallographic properties and wide variety of optically addressable defects.
As a more mathematically/theoretically minded student, I'd like to do a project that has intersections with both computational materials science and quantum information. I would like to use Quantum Espresso to use density functional theory to model color centers and gamma-point phonons in silicon carbide. I'm open to changing the project to something else more suitable as well; I don't know if this is well-posed as a "research question".
I'm still trying to figure out which approachable research question to ask; that's the impossible part for me right now, because I simply don't have the background. I could use some guidance on this.
